# How to create ROS2 library with dependence installed with CMake FetchContent?

Tags: ros2, c++, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to create a package that combines the rclcpp libraries and an external library installed with CMake FetchContent. How do I properly create a cmake file? I have already tried different ways, but I keep getting different errors. [Here](https://github.com/MrLeonardPak/ros-test/tree/foxy/test-external-lib) two package for example. An external-lib package contains an external library, and an executor package includes a external-lib package.
If I use the command **ament_target_dependencies()** then I catch the error: **ament_target_dependencies() the passed package name 'cli' was not found**.
If I use the command **target_link_libraries()** then I catch the error: **The following imported targets are referenced, but are missing: cli::cli**.

I appreciate your help, thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/409683/how-to-create-ros2-library-with-dependence-installed-with-cmake-fetchcontent?/) by [Mr_Leonard](https://answers.ros.org/users/120210/mr_leonard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2022-11-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to build it with the following changes.

---

In test-external-lib/external-lib/CMakeLists.txt
create shared library instead of static

```
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED src/my-lib.cc)
```

---

And in test-external-lib/executor/CMakeLists.txt, use

```
#ament_target_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} external-lib)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC external-lib::external-lib)
```

---

Finally, in test-external-lib/executor/src/exec.cc

```
auto tmp = new Consol();
tmp->Run(argc, argv);
```

---

Edit after comment :

You can use STATIC library too.

In **test-external-lib/external-lib/CMakeLists.txt**, do the following 2 changes

1. ament couldnt find cli, so link it with **target_link_libraries**

   #target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE cli::cli rclcpp::rclcpp)
   target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE cli::cli)
   ament_target_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC rclcpp)
2. export cli too

   #ament_export_dependencies(rclcpp)
   ament_export_dependencies(rclcpp cli)

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2022-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mr_Leonard](https://answers.ros.org/users/120210/mr_leonard/) on 2022-11-23**:
Thanks for your reply! Yes, with your changes the example worked. But it's strange. Why should we use a dynamic library? And it seems that dependency export stopped working. I move *#include  rclcpp.hpp* from source file to header file in "external-lib" package, and the 'executor' package can not find the rclcpp lib in "external-lib" `s file. This only works if you directly include rclcpp in the cmake file of the executor package. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? [Link](https://github.com/MrLeonardPak/ros-test/tree/foxy/test-external-lib)

**Comment by [Mr_Leonard](https://answers.ros.org/users/120210/mr_leonard/) on 2022-11-24**:
I updated the repo with your changes and it works, but only with a SHARED  property. If I set STATIC property I get this error *"The following imported targets are referenced, but are missing: cli::cli"*